# Two way binding when deleting all input doesnt work 2 times in a row

Tags: angular

I was trying to make it impossible for a input to be empty, however, when using "select all + backspace" , it updates the input only every other try.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-ece8aj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
How to reproduce:

1. Select the input
2. CTRL + A
3. Delete
4. (The input will autofill)
5. Ctrl + A
6. Delete again
7. --- The input doesnt auto fill

I've tried even using the change detector ref but it didn't work. How could I approach this? I don't think using settimeout will be a good solution (I've tried, and it works using setTimeout())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a funny bug. I guess Angular change detection did not get the update in time that the value of `ngModel` changed. So, it thinks that the value just went from `CANT BE EMPTY` to `CANT BE EMPTY`, and therefore did not refresh the html.

Solution is to force change detection before setting `this.name`. Now it knows that the value is changing from an empty string to `CANT BE EMPTY` and the html refreshes.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private detectChange: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  name = 'Angular 5';

  changeModel(value) {
    if (!value) {
      this.detectChange.detectChanges();
      this.name = 'CANT BE EMPTY';
    }
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-project-lknxj4?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks! What I had tried before with the changeDetector was using it after the "this.name" attribution.
But still doesnt make sense to me why adding it later wouldn't work

Comment: Yeah it seems like a bug in change detection, maybe worth reporting. It's possible the switch just happens too fast though, change detection probably doesn't have time to detect the empty string, because you switch it back so fast.

Comment: Also worth mentioning the `[placeholder]="message"` attribute of html inputs, they provide a similar function.

Comment: This is no bug and is an expected behavior. When input is cleared 2nd time, the value of `name` property remains the same and hence Angular won't update the view data binding.

Comment: Well, no. You can console.log() the name and see that it changes to an empty string (through two way binding) and then changes back to `CANT BE EMPTY`.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton , The placeholder wouldnt meet the requirements that I needed for my task, so that is why I did this way. ( I had to default the value to value if the user ever cleared the entire input )

Comment: @ChrisHamilton yes it's true that within `changeModel` it would be empty string, but that happens within same change detection cycle. It's as good as setting `name` as empty string and setting it to `CANT BE EMPTY` immediately on next line. And that's the exact reason why it didn't worked when Caio tried to call `detectChanges` after `this.name`.